# Get value from array in lua

Tags: arrays, indexing, printing, lua

I have the following array

```
local Array = {}
Array[1] = {"Value_A", "Value_B", "Value_C", "Value_D"}
Array[2] = {"Value_E", "Value_F", "Value_G", "Value_H"}
Array[3] = {"Value_I", "Value_J", "Value_K", "Value_L"}
```

and I know I can print the values of every array item at once with

```
for k, v in ipairs(Array) do
  print(k, v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4])
end
```

but I'd like to print the values of specific array items.

How can I do that?

Comment: `for k, v in pairs(Array[2]) do   print(k, v) end`

Comment: Thanks, but now I have the problem that I can only print v instead of v[1], v[2] etc.

Comment: Mike's code does what you requested.

Comment: Yes, but is there no way to seperate the values to print?

Comment: hard to understand you, just print what you want

Comment: Well, I want to seperate the four values I got. If I print v, I now get all four values at once.

Comment: `print(Array[2][3])` to print separately

Comment: well if you are unable to tell people what you want you will never be able to tell a computer what you want it to do.... edit your question, give the input and the desired output.

Comment: @cbrgmr If you want to print the values on the same line use `io.write()` instead of `print()` like so: `for k, v in pairs(Array[2]) do io.write(v,'\t') end`

Comment: Aside: Be careful using foreign terms like "array." Doing so might make you believe that `ipairs` will behave differently than it [does](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs), similarly with `#`.

Answer (score 2):

From reading your post and comments it seems to me you want to print every value separately instead of it all being on one line.

To do this you would need another for loop to iterate through all the values.

```
for k, v in ipairs(Array) do
          print(k)
          for i=1, #v do print(v[i]) end
          print() // This will just print a new line
end
```

Output:

```
1
Value_A
Value_B
Value_C
Value_D

2
Value_E
Value_F
Value_G
Value_H

3
Value_I
Value_J
Value_K
Value_L
```